# How can you get rid of smoke?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

My group was exploring a cave system, we found food and decided to cook it. This meant starting a fire. Our DM then said that the cave was filling up with smoke and we all had to run out. I'm just wondering if there was anything we could have done to clean up the smoke instead of having to leave.

Can presdigitation "clean" it up? "You instantaneously clean or soil an object no larger than 1 cubic foot." Can't a wizard just constantly clean the 1 cubic foot of air above the fire, minimising smoke?

Comment: @carrotsoup Thanks for clarifying. I've reopened the question. :)

Comment: @carrotsoup from your comment in the answer below, you seem to be with a X Y problem. You don't want to get rid of the smoke (The X you asked for). You actually want to have way to keep hidden in the cave while enjoying a hearthy fire (The **Y** you actually want to know about). [further reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I think the best thing we can do is to post a new question about your real problem, and close this one. **There is no shame in having a question closed**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a X Y question, that should be better adressed in a new question, since there is already a posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Prestidigitation* can indeed be used to scrub a 1-foot cube of smoke... every 6 seconds. Even in the best case scenario, your fire would be producing six times the amount to be cleaned.

There are other ways to manage, however. My recommendation is to use an illusion, such as *minor illusion*, to obscure the entrance of the cave. Unless the cave is shallow or the fire large, most of the smoke will disperse by the time it leaves your area, meaning the fire itself is more likely to draw attention... but any opaque illusion you employ will block the line of sight of anyone searching for your hidden characters, and unless they know the cave is supposed to be there or are searching every square foot physically, they might well not even get an Investigation check to discover the illusion. If smoke really is an issue, you can work with it, creating the illusion of a smoky, fire-filled cavern instead.

Say illusions are not an option- you can instead employ alternate sources of heat, use magic to protect yourself from the elements, or create a smokeless fire. You can also manipulate the air itself to scatter the smoke, via spells like *control winds*.

Comment: Air is hardly an object, see DMG page 246.

Comment: The warmth thing was just a generic example, our group was actually using it to cook. I would like to hear more about smokeless fire. Is it fire that is fueled by magic instead of actual fuel? Such as create bonfire or produce flames?

Comment: @carrotsoup from your comment, you seem to be with a X Y problem. You don't want to get rid of the smoke (The X you asked for). You actually want to have way to keep hidden in the cave while enjoying a hearthy fire (The **Y** you actually want to know about).

Comment: No, what actually happened was that the DM said the smoke filled up the cave system we were exploring and we had to struggle to get out. The situation given in the question was just a quick example. I just want to know so that the next time we start a fire indoors, we can avoid suffocating ourselves. Also, no one has minor illusion in the group.

Comment: @carrotsoup depends on the fire and the DM. Such a fire would definitely need to be magical, and I've always ruled that those fires which mention they aren't burning anything until they leave the caster (like _produce flame_) don't give off smoke until they burn something. YMMV, of course.

Comment: @enkryptor If you'd rule it that way, which is more than fair, you can still create "a puff of wind" with _prestidigitation_. How much is a puff of wind? I'd say no more than could be affected elsewhere in the spell. Say, a cubic foot... But it doesn't have a volume explicitly listed, so judgment call away.

Comment: @TheVagrantDog rules as written, it creates any "harmless sensory effect, *such as*" (not "one of the following") puff of wind, et cetera. So its strict interpretation is up to the DM by design.